# string split values in two columns, and then concatenate them into a new column

Tags: r, string, dataframe, apply, strsplit

I am trying to call the `str_split` function for both columns (`Proteins` and `Positions.within.proteins`), and then concatenate the corresponding values in a new column called `ID`.

```
df <- data.frame(Proteins = c("Q99755;A2A3N6", "O00329", "O00444", 
"O14965", "O14976", "Q6A1A2;O15530", "O43318", "O43526", "O43930;P51817", 
"O60331"), Positions.within.proteins = c("276;223", "708", "41", 
"162", "175", "84;111", "63", "628", "78;78", "270"))
```

Here are my codes.

```
my.function <- function(x, y){
  protein.names <- str_split(x, ";")[[1]]
  position.names <- str_split(y, ";")[[1]]
  ID <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(protein.names)){
      ID[i] <- paste(protein.names[i], position.names[i], sep ="_")
    }
  ID.2 <- unlist(ID)
  return(ID.2)
}
```

It works to some extent when I call the function on a single row.

```
row1 <- my.function(df$Proteins[1], df$Positions.within.proteins[1])
```

`"Q99755_276" "A2A3N6_223"`

But my questions are:

1. How to apply this function to the whole data frame?
2. How to convert `"Q99755_276" "A2A3N6_223"` to what I want `"Q99755_276;A2A3N6_223"`

I'd like to use the `apply` function, but am not sure if the `apply` function can take two arguments.

Here shows what it should look like.

```
df.final <- data.frame(Proteins = c("Q99755;A2A3N6", "O00329", "O00444", 
"O14965", "O14976", "Q6A1A2;O15530", "O43318", "O43526", "O43930;P51817", 
"O60331"), Positions.within.proteins = c("276;223", "708", "41", 
"162", "175", "84;111", "63", "628", "78;78", "270"), ID = c("Q99755_276;A2A3N6_223", 
"O00329_708", "O00444_41", "O14965_162", "O14976_175", "Q6A1A2_84;O15530_111", 
"O43318_63", "O43526_628", "O43930_78;P51817_78", "O60331_270"
))
```

Does anyone know how to achieve these? Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Can you show the sample table with IDs listed and how the data is ? Looks like you need to `join` `group_by` and `concatenate`

Comment: @JasonMathews Thanks for your reply! I updated my post. I showed the first 10 rows for the sample table.

Comment: A picture is not helpful, please share a reproducible sample of your data with `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Good to know this function `dput(head(data))`. Very helpful. I updated my post.

Comment: @GuedesBF I provided the editable code. Could you please explain what `\(x)` does in your code?

Comment: I had not seen your data yet. I have an answer now (see below). `\(x)`corresponds to the new lambda (anonymous) function synthax, as of R version 4.1

Comment: You can check this link explaining the new anonymous function synthax: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/new-features-in-r-4-1-0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **your function** and the **tidyverse**

Use `mutate()` with `map2(.f = my.function)` to create a nested ID column containing a list column with all IDs per row(some have 1 ID, some have two in the example data). Then you can `unnest_wider()` to create several different ID columns, which you can latter collapse using `tidyr::unite()`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(ID=map2(Proteins, Positions.within.proteins, my.function))%>%
        unnest_wider(ID, names_sep = '.')%>%
        unite(contains('ID'), col='ID', remove = TRUE, sep=";", na.rm=TRUE)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
   Proteins      Positions.within.proteins ID                   
   <chr>         <chr>                     <chr>                
 1 Q99755;A2A3N6 276;223                   Q99755_276;A2A3N6_223
 2 O00329        708                       O00329_708           
 3 O00444        41                        O00444_41            
 4 O14965        162                       O14965_162           
 5 O14976        175                       O14976_175           
 6 Q6A1A2;O15530 84;111                    Q6A1A2_84;O15530_111 
 7 O43318        63                        O43318_63            
 8 O43526        628                       O43526_628           
 9 O43930;P51817 78;78                     O43930_78;P51817_78  
10 O60331        270                       O60331_270
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `tidyr::unite()`:

```
tidyr::unite(data = iris, col = "new_column", Species, Sepal.Length, sep = ";")
```

Try that out. It takes a data frame (iris in this case), the name of your new column (new_column), the columns you would like to concatenate together (Species and Sepal.Length), and a value you would like to separate them by (a semicolon). `tidyr::separate()` is the opposite of `unite()`--it makes two new columns based on a delimiter found in the original.

**Edit**

Alright, you need to get a bit more creative...Try breaking each protein into its own column with `tidyr::separate()`, do the same for the protein position, then unite each protein with its position. Then, unite both proteins together with a semicolon as the delimiter. Finally, remove missing values for the cases where only one protein was used (which will always have the same form, at the end in `;NA_NA` format). Viola:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  separate(col = Proteins, c("protein1", "protein2"), ";", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  separate(col = Positions.within.proteins, into = c("position_p1", "position_p2"), ";", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  unite(col = "id_part1", sep = "_", protein1, position_p1) %>% 
  unite(col = "id_part2", sep = "_", protein2, position_p2) %>% 
  unite(col = "id", sep = ";", id_part1, id_part2) %>% 
  mutate(id = str_remove_all(id, ";NA_NA"))
```

**Another Edit**

I did some benchmarking, and my implementation is a bit faster, too:

```
rbenchmark::benchmark(
  mine = df %>% 
    separate(col = Proteins, c("protein1", "protein2"), ";", remove = FALSE) %>% 
    separate(col = Positions.within.proteins, into = c("position_p1", "position_p2"), ";", remove = FALSE) %>% 
    unite(col = "id_part1", sep = "_", protein1, position_p1) %>% 
    unite(col = "id_part2", sep = "_", protein2, position_p2) %>% 
    unite(col = "id", sep = ";", id_part1, id_part2) %>% 
    mutate(id = str_remove_all(id, ";NA_NA")),
  
alt_implementation = df %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(ID = map2(Proteins, Positions.within.proteins, my.function)) %>%
    unnest_wider(ID, names_sep = '.') %>%
    unite(contains('ID'), col = 'ID', remove = TRUE, sep = ";", na.rm = TRUE),

replications = 1000
)
#                  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1                mine         1000    9.06    1.000      8.97     0.05         NA        NA
# 2  alt_implementation         1000   11.77    1.299     11.73     0.00         NA        NA
```

Comment: No, `tidyr::unite` just simply concatenates two columns together.  What I want is more complicated than that. For example, `tidyr::unite` will combine `Q99755;A2A3N6` and `276;223` to give `Q99755;A2A3N6;276;223`. But what I want is `Q99755_276;A2A3N6_223`

Comment: I was thinking about a separate %>% separate %>% unite %>% unite solution too, but you got it first. Nice job. Although a litle verbose, this solution is easy to understand. I dont think this tiny diference in performance is relevant though.

Comment: @GuedesBF You're probably right about the performance, but you never know. Medical datasets tend to be unruly. Benchmarking was done out of curiosity more than anything else. Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: I am a physician myself, yes, "unruly" is a good description of medical datasets...

Comment: rowwise is not needed in the alternative implementation

Answer (score 1):

A brief base R solution.

```
df$ID <- apply(df, 1, \(x) paste(do.call(\(y, z) paste0(y, "_", z), 
                                         unname(strsplit(x, ';'))), collapse=';'))
df
#         Proteins Positions.within.proteins                    ID
# 1  Q99755;A2A3N6                   276;223 Q99755_276;A2A3N6_223
# 2         O00329                       708            O00329_708
# 3         O00444                        41             O00444_41
# 4         O14965                       162            O14965_162
# 5         O14976                       175            O14976_175
# 6  Q6A1A2;O15530                    84;111  Q6A1A2_84;O15530_111
# 7         O43318                        63             O43318_63
# 8         O43526                       628            O43526_628
# 9  O43930;P51817                     78;78   O43930_78;P51817_78
# 10        O60331                       270            O60331_270
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is base R way using `strsplit` and `mapply` -

```
df$ID <- mapply(function(x, y) paste(x, y, collapse = ';', sep = '_'), 
        strsplit(df$Proteins, ';'), strsplit(df$Positions.within.proteins, ';'))
df

#        Proteins Positions.within.proteins                    ID
#1  Q99755;A2A3N6                   276;223 Q99755_276;A2A3N6_223
#2         O00329                       708            O00329_708
#3         O00444                        41             O00444_41
#4         O14965                       162            O14965_162
#5         O14976                       175            O14976_175
#6  Q6A1A2;O15530                    84;111  Q6A1A2_84;O15530_111
#7         O43318                        63             O43318_63
#8         O43526                       628            O43526_628
#9  O43930;P51817                     78;78   O43930_78;P51817_78
#10        O60331                       270            O60331_270
```